# print controller variable outside of ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to print the current pages name outside of the `ng-view` div, but the controller does not have access to that.

For example:

```
  <nav>
     <li>{{currentPage}}</li>
  </nav>
  <div ng-view>
     <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
```

so in my controller when i put:

```
$scope.currentPage = 'Welcome to home page';
```

it wont print it, how can i fix this?

- Or should i put a custom variable in routeProvider and print that?

Comment: apply `ng-controller="controllerName"` to one `<div>`, then put your above HTML code into it. so may be it will work

Comment: actually i dont want to do that, cause its Dynamic on each page, it should change

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your ng-view's controller is not available in the nav as its outside the ng-view. You could add a controller for the nav and set $scope.currentPage indide that coontroller.

For passing name of currentpage from ng-view to nav-controller there are many ways. One would be to inject $rootScope into both and pass data using $rootScope.$emit.

Another way would be to inject a common service into both controllers for that.

Comment: Thank you, but isnt  that possible to pass the variable directly from he routeProvider, and access that to the view ?

Comment: you can add views: {.. edit: {.. then add templateUrl and controller } } in your $routeprovider
then use it in view like : `<div ui-view="edit" >` that means you can pass parameter in these way, but I am not sure about it, because i used this way in $stateProvider